# How do I set a limit for loading messages in a chat to save user traffic?

Tags: javascript, css, chat

How do I set a limit for loading messages in a chat to save user traffic? Let's say there are 10,000 messages. If we download everything, it will take an unimaginable amount of traffic. What if there are pictures? And so will be loaded only let's say 30. And it will load 30 messages at a time when scrolling. Please help me. Thank you in advance. I use a translator.

Comment: Please add relevant code you use - no code no help.

Comment: provide Code and backend language.

Answer (score 0):

the answer splits into 2:

1. the request from the server should allow the limitation of the number of objects. for the sake of the example if the API is using GET, then the request might look like URL/messages.api?from=1&to=30
2. for scrolling purposes you keep a counter variable, then have an `onScroll` event set that would call a function to call the API for the next set of messages, and render the results.

if you'd add code I can be more specific
you can look at an example code that I wrote here:
https://42knots.midrehov.com/42/apps/news.html